# ToString Format

Tags: c#, vb.net, string.format

I have an String like this "00.00-0-00" and I need to transform like this "0000-0/00"

I already tried:
field.ToString("####-##/##") ' without success
String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:####-#/##}", field) 'without success

Any help with that?

Comment: what is the data type of the field?  It sounds like a string that contains the `.` and the two `-`s

Comment: yes, the data type is string and the return information should be string as well

Comment: If original type is the `String`, then `NumberFormat` used by you will not work, because numbers will be handled as string not a integer. You need manually change string value to another presentation format

Comment: Is your preference VB or C#? I see you have both tagged.

Comment: @TonyL., is it metter? :) Same .NET framework

Comment: @Fabio, Not much I suppose, but I like to post code that the asking user can more or less copy/paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it (val is input string)

```
  string.Format(@"{0}{1}-{2}/{3}",
                   val.Substring(0,2),
                   val.Substring(3,2),
                   val.Substring(6,1),
                   val.Substring(8,2));
```

If you don't like string.Format you could also use concatenation (`+`)

Answer (score 1):

My version which work if your original format doesn't change(as other answers based too)

```vb
Dim oldString As String = "00.00-0-00"
Dim parts As String() = oldString.Split({"."c, "-"c})
Dim result As String = _
    String.Format("{0}{1}-{2}/{3}", parts(0), parts(1), parts(2), parts(3)))
```

C# version

```cs
string original = "00.00-00-00";
string[] parts = original.Split(new char[] {'.', '-'});
string result = String.Format("{0}{1}-{2}/{3}", parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your string will always be in the format, you could just do it manually. If you need to do this a lot, you could just create a function to do it.

```
 Dim oldString As String = "00.00-0-00"
 Dim newString As String = MakeNewString(oldString)
```

Function to call:

```
Function MakeNewString(oldString As String) As String
    Dim noPeriod As String = Replace(oldString, ".", "")
    Return Split(noPeriod, "-")(0) & "-" & Split(noPeriod, "-")(1) & "/" & Split(noPeriod, "-")(2)
End Function
```

In C#:

```
string oldString = "00.00-0-00";
string newString = MakeNewString(oldString);
```

C# Function:

```
public string MakeNewString(string oldString)
{
    string noPeriod = Strings.Replace(oldString, ".", "");
    return Strings.Split(noPeriod, "-")(0) + "-" + Strings.Split(noPeriod, "-")(1) + "/" + Strings.Split(noPeriod, "-")(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your format is always "00.00-0-00", then you can use `Regex.Replace()` like this:

VB.NET

```
Dim data As String = "00.00-0-00"
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(data, "(\d+)\.(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)", "$1$2-$3/$4"))
```

C#

```
string data = "00.00-0-00";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(data, "(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)", "$1$2-$3/$4"));
```

Results:

```
0000-0/00
```

The `Regex` is capturing all of the digits into groups and you just put the groups back together with whatever delimiter you want.